# Entire C: disk is read-only after power outage

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I have a SATA express m.2 256 gb for my C: drive and after power outage something has happened to it and Windows constantly crashes.

Using diskpart when clean it, it doesn't have any effect.

Using kubuntu partition manager I get the same result.

And I can't use chkdsk on it.

And when I restart it goes back to its previous state

What should I do to fix this?

I checked the m.2 drive it doesn't have any read-only pins or slides or anything like that so its not hardware (probably)

I deleted, formatted, cleaned the SSD using various tools and partition managers but it still had no effect. All the data remained and my efforts had no effect. I don't know what else to do.

EDIT:

It turns out that due to power outage my SSD is a goner. I'll buy a new SSD from samsung: 970 Pro Plus 500GB Thanx for the replies and best regards

Comment: Linux has no tools to actually fix errors on NTFS file systems. You must use Windows tools.

Comment: what about hiren's boot? (is there any way to save my files and C drive?)

Comment: It may work (probably not) but AFAIK, at the very least, you need to disable Secure Boot in UEFI or it won't boot.

Comment: Slightly confused, but when you say this, “All the data remained and my efforts had no effect.” Do you want to simply reuse the SSD after wiping it out? Or do you want to recover the drive as-is so data is retained? Wiping the drive should be easier than attempting recovery, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting into cmd, if it is possible( Windows will probably give you screen, where you're prompted to repair, so select advanced options and Command prompt).

Then try these steps in cmd:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk 0
attributes disk clear readonly
```

Comment: didn't work: DiskPart failed to clear disk attributes.

Comment: That happens... It looks like there is another problem...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that due to power outage my SSD is a goner.
I'll buy a new SSD from samsung: 970 Pro Plus 500GB
Thanx for the replies and best regards